# how to parse multi index values and create a csv file while parsing json data in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have few static key columns EmployeeId,type and few columns coming from first FOR loop.

While in the second FOR loop if i have a specific key then only values should be appended to the existing data frame columns else whatever the columns getting fetched from first for loop should remain same.

**First For Loop Output:**

```
"EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End","Country","Target","CountryId","TargetId"
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","","",""
```

**After Second For Loop i have below output:**

```
"EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End","Country","Target","CountryId","TargetId"
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","AMAZON","1",""
"Emp1","Metal","1212121212","2000-06-17","9999-12-31","","FLIPKART","2",""
```

As per code if i have Employee tag available , i have got above 2 records but i may have few json files without Employee tag then output should remain same as per First Loop Output.

But i am getting 0 records as per my code. Please help me if my way of coding is wrong.

Really sorry -- If the way of asking question is not clear , as i am new to python .  Please find the code in the below hyper link

**Please find below code**

```
    for i in range(len(json_file['enty'])):
        temp = {}
        temp['EmployeeId'] = json_file['enty'][i]['id']
        temp['type'] = json_file['enty'][i]['type']
        for key in json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes'].keys():        
            try:
                temp[key] = json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes'][key]['values'][0]['value']
            except:
                temp[key] = None      

        for key in json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes'].keys(): 
            if(key == 'Employee'):
                for j in range(len(json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'])):
                    for key in json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'][j].keys():
                        try:
                            temp[key] = json_file['enty'][i]['data']['attributes']['Employee']['group'][j][key]['values'][0]['value']
                        except:
                            temp[key] = None

                    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([temp])
                    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], sort=True)

    # Rearranging columns
    df = df[['EmployeeId', 'type'] + [col for col in df.columns if col not in ['EmployeeId', 'type']]]

    # Writing the dataset
    df[columns_list].to_csv("Test22.csv", index=False, quotechar='"', quoting=1)
```

If Employee Tag is not available i am getting 0 records as output but i am expecting 1 record as per output of first FOR loop. If the "Employee tag" is available then i am expecting 2 records along with my static columns "EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End", else if the tag is not available then all the static columns "EmployeeId","type","KeyColumn","Start","End", and remaining columns as blanks

[enter link description here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=672e1c8e543047a5a236d44c589f6476)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long solution with modifying your code, so adding one more loop, changing indexes, as well as modifying the `range` parameters:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

num = max([len(v) for k,v in json_file['data'][0]['data1'].items()])
for i in range(num):
    temp = {}
    temp['Empid'] = json_file['data'][0]['Empid']
    temp['Empname'] = json_file['data'][0]['Empname']
    for key in json_file['data'][0]['data1'].keys():
        if key not in temp:
            temp[key] = []
        try:
            for j in range(len(json_file['data'][0]['data1'][key])):
                temp[key].append(json_file['data'][0]['data1'][key][j]['relative']['id']) 
        except:
            temp[key] = None                    
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([temp])
    df = pd.concat([df, temp_df],ignore_index=True)
for i in json_file['data'][0]['data1'].keys():
    df[i] = pd.Series([x for y in df[i].tolist() for x in y]).drop_duplicates()
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
  Empid Empname    XXXX   YYYYY
0  1234     ABC  Naveen   Kumar
1  1234     ABC     NaN  Rajesh
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I tried but i am getting an error " IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: I just handled as per my data and this approach worked... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Need one suggestion ..in one of the function .. Can i ask ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.  I have attached one screen shot. I am getting " TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable " . Please please help me with any suggestion..

Comment: Problem: Actually i have " Employee" Tag as multi valued . So for some Json files i may have "EmployeeTag" but for some Json files i may not have it. To over come i have provided "IF" condition. But if tag is not available i am getting 0 records before i use the above Max(Len) suggestion . My desire output is like if i have "Employee" Tag then i need to get the values , if not i should get them as blank and one record need to be displayed. to handle this scenario i have added this suggestion and i am facing TypeError

Comment: its working but i am getting 0 records but if the tag is not available i should get one record because i have some key columns and along with the key columns remaining should be printed as blank..

Sample FIle

https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=672e1c8e543047a5a236d44c589f6476

Comment: Can i modify the question and add sample file and expected output ?

Comment: @avinash Sorry but can i solve this in around 14 hours?

Comment: :Sure. I will wait for your reply , can i edit the question in the same page itself ? or can i drop you mail ?

Comment: Hi.. Have you got any chance to look.. Please help me

Comment: @avinash Sorry for my late reply, you can send me an email

Comment: Can you help me with your mail id .. ?

Comment: @avinash What's desired output?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195446/discussion-between-u9-forward-and-avinash).

Comment: @Waiting for your reply :)

Comment: i am getting default values  "There is text!!!" . instead of that how can i get original values and that solution is creating duplicates...